# Is there any way I can load text on an image using onload function?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, dom

I have used an image in the background of my web page. Now what I want is, after the entire image is loaded, a text should be documented on the same. For that I have done the following up till now:-

```
<body onload = "myFunction()">
<script>
function myFunction() {
  setTimeout(function(){ document.write("<h1>H"); }, 1000);
  setTimeout(function(){ document.write("E"); }, 2000);
  setTimeout(function(){ document.write("L"); }, 3000);
  setTimeout(function(){ document.write("L"); }, 4000);
  setTimeout(function(){ document.write("O</h1>"); }, 5000);
}
</script>
</body>
```

The above works fine without an image, but it doesn't load at all when applied to an image.

Adding the class style:-

Here, our prime focus is on the very first image which the .bgimg-1 contains.

```
<style>

.bgimg-1, .bgimg-2, .bgimg-3, .bgimg-4, .bgimg-5 { 
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.65;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;

}

.bgimg-1 {
  background-image: url("Images/Web.jpg");
  min-height: 100%;
}

</style>

<body>

   <div class="bgimg-1">
  <div class="caption">

        <h1></h1>

</div>
</div>

  <script>
          var img = document.querySelector('img');
          var h1 = document.querySelector('h1');


          img.addEventListener('load', myFunction)
          img.addEventListener('error', function() {
            alert('error')
          })


          function myFunction() {
            setTimeout(function() {
              h1.innerHTML += ("H");
            }, 1000);
            setTimeout(function() {
              h1.innerHTML += ("E");
            }, 2000);
            setTimeout(function() {
              h1.innerHTML += ("L");
            }, 3000);
            setTimeout(function() {
              h1.innerHTML += ("L");
            }, 4000);
            setTimeout(function() {
              h1.innerHTML += ("O");
            }, 5000);
          }


        </script>


   </body>
```

Note:- Only the relevant content code is added here.

Thank youenter code here

Comment: Use `onload` on your `<img>`, not `<body>`

Comment: I tried doing that but the image disappears and the text starts displaying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var img = document.querySelector('.bgimg-1');
var h1 = document.querySelector('h1');

// create image to detect when loaded
var tempImg = new Image(100, 200);
tempImg.src = "https://s14-eu5.startpage.com/cgi-bin/serveimage?url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedia1.tenor.com%2Fimages%2F2ddd441a094881de33cd8b283aec1321%2Ftenor.gif%3Fitemid%3D12124817&sp=286b17e46141fd3ae6dd535ee83d0118&anticache=671261";
document.body.appendChild(tempImg);

tempImg.addEventListener('load', myFunction)
tempImg.addEventListener('error', function() {
  alert('error');
})


function myFunction() {
  // set background-image property to image source
  img.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + tempImg.src + ")";

  // remove image after loaded
  tempImg.parentNode.removeChild(tempImg);

  setTimeout(function() {
    h1.innerHTML += ("H");
  }, 1000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    h1.innerHTML += ("E");
  }, 2000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    h1.innerHTML += ("L");
  }, 3000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    h1.innerHTML += ("L");
  }, 4000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    h1.innerHTML += ("O");
  }, 5000);
}
```

```css
.bgimg-1 {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0em;
  left: 1em;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="bgimg-1">
    <div class="caption">
      <h1></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Keeping your existing function, just add a 'load' event listener to the image and add another element to display the message.

```js
var img = document.querySelector('img');
var h1 = document.querySelector('h1');


img.addEventListener('load', myFunction)
img.addEventListener('error', function() {
  alert('error')
})


function myFunction() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    h1.innerHTML += ("H");
  }, 1000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    h1.innerHTML += ("E");
  }, 2000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    h1.innerHTML += ("L");
  }, 3000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    h1.innerHTML += ("L");
  }, 4000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    h1.innerHTML += ("O");
  }, 5000);
}
```

```css
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3em;
  left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/friendlylooking-european-teenager-dressed-in-yellow-pulover-saying-picture-id976585934?k=6&m=976585934&s=612x612&w=0&h=C9-wIeuzewmBfBmRU6oSqt9jky9ZOAbB7JHFmH6Bf3k=">
  <h1></h1>
</body>
```

**Edit:** Updated answer for updated question - A background image doesn't have a `load` event, so in order to  do this, you'd create a new `Image()` object and set its `source` to the image you want. Then listen for that image to load. When it does, set your div's `backgroundImage` to the image source and remove the created image.

```js
var img = document.querySelector('.bgimg-1');
var h1 = document.querySelector('h1');

// create image to detect when loaded
var tempImg = new Image(100, 200);
tempImg.src = "https://s14-eu5.startpage.com/cgi-bin/serveimage?url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedia1.tenor.com%2Fimages%2F2ddd441a094881de33cd8b283aec1321%2Ftenor.gif%3Fitemid%3D12124817&sp=286b17e46141fd3ae6dd535ee83d0118&anticache=671261";
document.body.appendChild(tempImg);

tempImg.addEventListener('load', myFunction)
tempImg.addEventListener('error', function() {
  alert('error');
})


function myFunction() {
  // set background-image property to image source
  img.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + tempImg.src + ")";

  // remove image after loaded
  tempImg.parentNode.removeChild(tempImg);

  setTimeout(function() {
    h1.innerHTML += ("H");
  }, 1000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    h1.innerHTML += ("E");
  }, 2000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    h1.innerHTML += ("L");
  }, 3000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    h1.innerHTML += ("L");
  }, 4000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    h1.innerHTML += ("O");
  }, 5000);
}
```

```css
.bgimg-1 {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0em;
  left: 1em;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="bgimg-1">
    <div class="caption">
      <h1></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Although your code works for me when I add the image inside the body tag, when I use it inside a class, it doesn't work. Actually, I am using the Parallax effect on all these images, so the image should be within the class. I have edited my code and added the class style and some other relevant code for your reference. Thank you

Comment: @ShashankkShekarChaturvedi I've updated my answer to reflect this change.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `document.write`. You should also avoid using `setTimeout` unless you really need it.

That said, what you need to do is to add a `load` [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to your image. Once it loads, you can make your message visible.

Here's a very basic example.

```js
const image = document.querySelector('.image');
const message = document.querySelector('.message');

image.addEventListener('load', () => {
  message.classList.remove('hide')
});
```

```css
.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.message {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 1em;
  padding: 3em;
  position: fixed;
  top: 1em;
  left: 1em;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<img class="image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1402787/pexels-photo-1402787.jpeg">

<div class="message hide">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I am using setTimeout because I want each word to display after some milliseconds and not in one go. Thank you for your solution but the text should be written directly on the image without any other div or background.